# Invariant lagrangian under $SU(N)$

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, group-theory, invariants

I know from group theory that $ \bar{R} \otimes R \otimes A= 1 \oplus \dots$ where $A$ is the adjoint representation. My question is how to build the singlet, I thought a generalization of Rodriguez's formula to make lagrangian invariant, in particular for $SU(N)$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}= \bar{\psi} ( A^a T^a) \psi , \quad a=1, \dots N^2-1 , \quad T^a \in \mathbb{R}^{dim \,{R} \times dim \,{R}}
\end{equation}
where the field $\psi$ transform in $R$ and $A$ in the adjoint representation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I prefer the physicists approach to such things. Put in explicit indices on all your objects, $\psi^i$, ${\bar \psi}_i$, $(T^a)^i{}_j$, etc. Then put all your fields together so all the indices match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the tensor product of the fundamental with the antifundamental makes a singlet plus the adjoint. If you then have another adjoint, the only way to make a singlet is to take the product of the two adjoints. By this is easy to see that is $\psi_i\sim\Box$ and $\overline{\psi}\,^i \sim \overline{\Box}$ then $$\overline{\psi}\,^i\psi_j \sim \text{Adj}$$ and therefore if $(A^a T^a)^i_j \sim \text{Adj}$ you easily make the singlet by contracting the indices $\overline{\psi}\,^i (A^aT^a)_i^j \psi_j$.